# Kiel vi dirus "comb-over" en Esperanto?

Tags: word-formation

Ĉu ekzistas vorto aŭ termo por "comb-over" en Esperanto (ekzemple "he has a really bad comb-over")? Mi provis ĉiun kombinaĵo de "komb-" kaj "supr-" ke mi povus elpensi.

Comment: "comb-over" seems to have several meanings: a way to disguise bald spots (see [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/comb-over) and [English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comb_over)) or a more general class of hair styles (see e.g. [here](https://www.allthingshair.com/en-us/mens-hairstyles/quiff/what-is-a-comb-over/), [here](https://www.menshairstylesnow.com/comb-over-hairstyles-for-men/) and [here](https://www.wikihow.com/Do-a-Comb-Over)).

Comment: @das-g I just asked out of curiosity because of a comment on one of Evildea's videos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NH_g3YynNAw&lc=UgxKzfcBbNTM92m8TE94AaABAg&ab_channel=Evildea

Comment: Ĉu do la demando temas pri la nuna harar-stilo de Evildea (kaj do pri la unua senco de la esprimo)?

Comment: Se temas pri la harar-stilo de Evildea, tio estas ja laŭdifine dia :-O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**kombostilo** = comb-over

Estas kelkaj similaj esprimebloj

- *frizo* = ne simpla kombado, sed metia / per iloj
- *harstilo* = tro nespecifa
- *kombo* = unufoja kombado
- *transkomb(ad)o* = *comb-over* por kalva parto
- *kombostilo* = *comb-over*, nespecifa

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest
Surkombado
Kaŝkombado

Answer (score 1):

Ne ekzistas tiu vorto en Esperanto. Vi devas priskribi la aferon kun aliaj vortoj, ekzemple, "Ri kombas la harojn sur sian kalvecon por kaŝi ĝin, sed aspektas tre malbone."

Kiam mi tradukas la anglan en la ĉinan, ĉiam mi devas reverki tiel, ĉar la lingvoj ne havas la samajn vortojn. Esperanto ja estas pli facila, sed oni ne atendu, ke ĝi havu ĉiun vorton el ĉiu lingvo. Tio ĉiukaze estas mia propono.